# Hidden cell to be shown when in printing

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Excel file which is edited repeatedly. So there is a modification date Cell which is filled by modification date.

I want the cell to not be visible until a user clicks on the print button and that date would be shown in paper. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't hide a single cell; it has to be an entire row or column. In this example we'll assume you're going to hide an entire row.

You can hide the row manually:

[image]

or in VBA, assuming it's cell D1 on Sheet1:

```
Sheet1.Range("D1").EntireRow.Hidden = True
```

Then to unhide the cell before printing, you could put something like this in the `Workbook_BeforePrint` event:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
    Sheet1.Range("D1").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End Sub
```

To access the `Workbook_BeforePrint` event, open the VBA editor (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F11</kbd>) and open the ThisWorkbook module. There you can select "BeforePrint" from a list of available events, or you can just type the code by hand.

[image]

Comment: see explanation above

Comment: and how can i hide it after print?

Comment: I can't keep expanding the solution; I suggest you post a new question. I will be happy to look at it, especially if you give a bit of recognition by upvoting. Come on, show us a little love!